# How to use SVG for inital Angular2 load

Tags: angular, svg

Instead of the Angular2's default application "Loading..", I would like to do a SVG Loading spinner. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply replace the "Loading..." text inside the `<my-app>` tags in your index.html file with any HTML or SVG and it should just render that content while the app loads and angular takes over rendering:

```
<my-app>
  <svg>
   <!-- your svg code here...-->
 </svg>
</my-app>
```